# .htaccess redirect when URL contains parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, parameters, url-rewriting

Yes, I searched the site and found many examples, but my .htacces skills are very limited, so NONE of examples worked for me after trying to modify them to suit my needs.

Put simply, if URL is like "index.php?/............" user should be redirect to example.com (ideally, to example.com instead of example.com/index.php) immediately.

I need this because I have an old domain that was used for forum, so I get thousands of requests like "example.com/index.php?/whatever" and all these virtual pages display the same content, which hurts my rankings badly.

My index.php file has NO parameters at all (but some other files have, so the rule shouldn't affect other files).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root (preferably *before* any other rules you have there)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Would you help me a bit more, please?

I also need URLs like index.php/? (note it's NOT index.php ?/ like in original example), and website.com?/ and website.com/? to be redirected to the index page. I tried modifying your example above, but none of my experiments did the trick